# Stone tile flooring with acoustic sound reduction requirement in condo

Tags: flooring, tile, stone, underlayment, backer-board

We just closed on a new condo and want to replace some of the old carpet with stone tiles. However, the HOA has a sound reduction requirement where the floors must pass acoustic testing with 55 IIC or better after install.

What should I use for the underlayment / backerboard? Can I use both an acoustic underlay with a backerboard like HardieBacker? Any other advice or suggestions on how to do this best so we don't end up failing the acoustic test? Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer or supplier of the stone tiles for any recommendations?